# RSS Enclosure is ignored

Tags: c#, wcf, rss

I'm trying to create a Podcast RSS feed using WCF.  The feed seems to be valid, but the enclosure tag is being ignored.  Any ideas?

Fixed now ... don't use file file:/// urls even if you are feeding yourself the files.

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>Joe Blow</title> 
    <link>http://google.com/</link> 
    <description>The Joe Blow Show</description> 
    <managingEditor>joeblow@gmail.com</managingEditor> 
    <category>Talk Radio</category> 
    <item>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">1342</guid> 
        <category>Podcast</category> 
        <title>Joe Blow Show #1</title> 
        <description>Joe Blow Show #1</description> 
        <pubDate>Mon, 01 Jun 2009 13:57:47 -0600</pubDate> 
        <enclosure url="file:///C:/JoeBlowShow1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" length="101725855" /> 
      </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The enclosure should not be stored on your hard drive. This should be a world accessible URL. (This assumes that you are publishing this on the web.)
2. Run the feed through a [feed validator](http://beta.feedvalidator.org/) to look for errors.